# Media Screen Applied are not working in Chrome either in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, media-queries

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide">
```

I tried all these both but neither of them is shown in DevTools Box.....Also installed Chrome 2nd latest version but no use.....
Also added the meta tag with viewport and device width which also didnt worked

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px ) and (min-width:769px ) 
{
/*
some css which is not working 
*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 324px ) and (min-width:427px ) 
{
/*
some css which is not working 
*/
}

 @media  (max-width: 1326px )  and (min-width: 1025px)
{
  .nav-color
  {
    width: 1200px;
  }
  .navbar-nav
  {
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link
  {
    font-size: 1rem;
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell what is the problem

Comment: Your CSS code is fine. Add your HTML code inside your question.